# mysql index prefix length is automatically set in ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, indexing, mysql

I have the following MyISAM table

```
mysql> show create table product_desc\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: product_desc
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `product_desc` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`description`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However when I want to alter the table (adding indexes) with the following command, I got the error.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE product_desc ADD INDEX `description` (`description`);
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

Strangely, this only happen on Mac OSX, but not on my ubuntu server. So I check the result table on my server and get this:

```
mysql> show indexes from product_desc;
+------------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| product_desc |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| product_desc |          1 | description |            1 | description | A         |           5 |      333 | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| product_desc |          1 | title       |            1 | title       | NULL      |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| product_desc |          1 | title       |            2 | description | NULL      |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
+------------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The interesting part is that `description` index automatically get a 333 prefix length.So my question is how does it happen like that? is there any configuration variables I need to set on MacOS my.cnf in order to get the same result?

Comment: Are you running exactly the same major/minor/release version of MySQL on both systems?  What versions are involved?

Comment: on ubuntu mysql version is: 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 and on MacOS version is 5.6.12, I pasted the detail in http://pastebin.com/cppRZHQs

Answer (score 0):

Your column size is too big to be indexed.

Prefixes can be up to 1000 bytes long (767 bytes for InnoDB tables).

This is a MySql limitation, not OS specific (but well storage engine specific)

Could you show the table details on the MacOS.

[MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-indexes.html)